# How to get count of dropped files in filepond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepond

I have implemented FilePond file upload, and it is working fine. However, I would like to display the number of files dropped into the drop zone at a given time and show the count of uploading files.

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change',function () {
        fileCount = this.files.length;
        console.log(fileCount );

    });
```

The above code provides the correct count of files using the change event.

However, I'm attempting to obtain the count of dropped files specifically, but below code does not seem to work for that purpose.

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
let droppedFileCount = 0;
pond.on('addfile', () => {
droppedFileCount = pond.getFiles().length;
console.log('Dropped file count:', droppedFileCount);
});
```

Any lead will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of dropped files specifically in FilePond, you can use the 'addfile' event listener. The code you provided is on the right track, but to display the count of dropped files at any given time, you need to keep track of both the number of files added and the number of files removed from the FilePond instance. Here's an updated and more comprehensive example:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
let droppedFileCount = 0;

pond.on('addfile', () => {
  droppedFileCount = pond.getFiles().length;
  console.log('Dropped file count:', droppedFileCount);
});

pond.on('removefile', () => {
  droppedFileCount = pond.getFiles().length;
  console.log('Dropped file count:', droppedFileCount);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have previously tried this code as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Victoria Hill!

All six of your answers here appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.